# Playwright: wait for selector using a regexp, to NOT contain specific text

Tags: java, playwright

I am using playwright in java and I have a page that runs javascript. After opening it shows "Loading..." and only when this disappears the content to be tested appears.

So, I want to load the (iframe) with a selector to check for the text "Loading..." to disappear. While I can select for the "headerMessage" etc. I don't get this working with the negated regexp. Is this not possible? What am I doing wrong?

`Frame frame = page.frame("tf_content").waitForSelector("#headerMessage :text-matches(\"!Loading...\")").ownerFrame();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Playwright has an assertion system. You can use it to wait until a lot of useful and smart conditions:

- Element to be visible
- Element Not to be visible
- Selector to have X count
- Element to be enabled
- Element attribute the have Y value

Import the class:

```
import static com.microsoft.playwright.assertions.PlaywrightAssertions.assertThat;
```

Code example:

```
assertThat(page.locator("//*[contains(text(), 'Loading...')]")).hasCount(0);
// or:
assertThat(page.locator("//*[contains(text(), 'Loading...')]")).isHidden();
```

After the assert has passed - you are good to go.